# create_node event triggers open_node event on parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I do not want the open-node event be triggered on creation of child node. Here is my implementation.

```
$(function () {
$("#tree").jstree({ 
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : [
            { 
                data : "/", 
                attr : { "id" : "root"},
                state : "closed",
                "children" : [ { "data" : "child1",
                                "attr" : { "id" : "child1.id" },
                                "children" : [ ] }
                             ]
            },
        ]
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm", "ui" ]
})
.bind("select_node.jstree",function(event, data) { $("#tree").jstree("create",.... });
.bind("open_node.jstree",function(event,data){ . . . });
```

Creating a node when selecting a node triggers event open_node which I do not want. The open_node event has different functioning for me. Can anyone help add a node without triggering of open_node event ?